# Media volume automatically goes to zero when removing headphones

Tags: settings, volume-control

Whenever I remove the headphone jack<sup>1</sup> while I have some media playing<sup>2</sup>, the file stops (which is what I want and expect) but the media volume also goes down to zero (which is unexpected and I would prefer not to happen).

If I pause the media file before removing the headphone jack this does not occur.

Is this a setting I missed? Is there a way I can prevent it from happening, or do I simply need to remember to pause before removing the jack?

---

<sup>1</sup> Samsung Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.0.4 (although this also happened with 4.0.2).

<sup>2</sup> I have observed this with DoggCatcher and Google Music.

Comment: Did you ever use Tasker or Locale to setup some sort of trigger (on headset removal) previously?

Comment: Haven't used either.

Comment: I've come to assume this is a bug, because I've experienced the same problem (along with [this seemingly related one](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23089/the-ui-sounds-on-my-galaxy-nexus-no-longer-play-how-can-i-re-enable-them)).

Comment: @eldar: Thanks for the pointer to Volume Control +. I think it'll be helpful (although not for the issue I'm currently having).

Comment: Just as a note there's a similar feature in Cyanogenmod (at least in 7) that when you plug/unplug your headphones it restores the volume to what it was in the same state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same problem with my phone until I uninstalled the turntable.fm app.  This is the post that clued me into the fix: https://forums.motorola.com/posts/bc23079218

Comment: That might be it. I did recently install that app. I'll uninstall and report back.

Comment: Well, what do you know? That appears to be the issue. Now why the %$@# turntable.fm would mess with a global setting like that is a mystery.

Comment: Nice find, by the way.

Comment: Oh wow. I've had other issues with TT.fm. They didn't develop that app very well :/. For example, I lost connection once and TT.fm (of all apps!) comes up with a screen saying I need a connection to continue using the app (I had already left a room and was no longer using the app before I lost the connection). Then I had a hard time getting that screen to go away, it was as if it kept popping up. Bizarre.

Comment: What a piece of junk. After uninstalling turntable.fm not only did this issue get fixed, but also my device stopped automatically turning off silent mode when plugged in to charge.